# What kind of code/instructions can make a MCU run at it's maximum power consumption

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to evaluate the maximum power consumption of a MCU (Renesas RX72N or RX651). It's not battery powered and it's never run in sleep mode. I am thinking I can write a piece of benchmark code, in C of course, that should do a lot of complex calculations. While the MCU is executing the calculations, I can measure the current drawn by the MCU and deduce what's its maximum power consumption level.  Is my understand correct?  If so, do you think what kind of code I should write or is there already some open source code to use  for the purpose?

Thanks in advance.
-woody

Comment: Read the datasheet.  Do you think you can really arrive at a better answer than the manufacturer's engineers?

Answer (score 0):

In general you just have to experiment.  There is no fixed answer.  First off check the datasheet, you certainly want flash on and all the peripherals out of reset.  Fastest clock is probably good but understand that running from flash does not necessarily scale up, depends on the part (do they have wait states that have a table relative to processor clock speed).

Changing states burns power.  So you want to try to flip as many as you can.  But it could be that you want to flip gpio or other external pins rather than try to get the processor core to pull more power.

You will want a nice meter for this one that can measure milliamps or milliwatts.

Things like multiply and divide in theory take a good percentage of chip space, if they implement it in one clock, but some of these mcus naturally won't do that, the instruction will be multi clock or at times the chip vendor can choose (if they buy an arm core for example).  But you may need to deal with data patterns to to get more consumption.  For core stuff you probably want to do as much register based stuff vs read/save things to memory.

You probably want to write the test code in assembly language. Will want to start with an infinite loop, branch to self, measure power/current. Complicate the loop, additional memory cycles, or alu operations, see if you can detect a power difference (you may find that you are not going to be able to make much difference with the core).  Depending on the mcu design you may/should get better execution performance running from ram, but it depends of course.  ram tends to be faster in mcus than flash.  then do things like flip gpio pins, leave them high, etc.  If you have LEDs turn them all on naturally, etc.

There is no one answer for this, so no one benchmark nor one solution pushes any random chip the hardest.  Assume that if possible to see a noticeable difference for a particular chip, that the test would be specific to that chip and not necessarily the same solution for other chips from the same company, much less chips from other companies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am current want to isolate consumption by the MCU although I agree that GPIOs and external peripherals will also drain the power.  What you mean by saying: "For core stuff you probably want to do as much register based stuff vs read/save things to memory"? Do you mean operating of registers will consume more power than operating on memory? Thanks.

Comment: well going out to ram will take time a clock cycle or few, while the processor maybe sits idle?  depends on the design of the processor, but either way you are possibly adding time per instruction which allows things to settle for that clock or few.  if you are more register heavy then in theory you save a clock or few per instruction and get more work done.   depends on the system design of the chip though.

Comment: you are already probably gated by the flash which is often slow relative to the processor, thus running from ram, or if there is a cache or a prefetch or something you can enable to try to get more instructions into the processor faster.